# How to make byte[] field required field properly?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I need to validate a `byte[]` in my model as `Required` but whenever I use `Data Annotation` `[Required]` on it, it won't do anything. Even if i choose a file it outputs error message.

Details:

Model:

```
Public class MyClass
{
   [Key]
   public int ID {get; set;}

   [Required]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public byte[] Image {get; set;}

   [Required]
   public byte[] Template {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
   <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
   <input type="file" id="file1" name="files" />
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   <%:Html.Label("Template") %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field"> 
   <input type="file" id="file2" name="files"/>
</div>
<p>
   <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
```

I've looked around the posts and notice people use custom validation but they have used `HttpPostedFileBase` as types of files instead of `byte[]` like me, for some reason when I try to use the same it errors with a missing ID for it... Even though the model has it's own ID declared.

EDIT:

Context - `OnModelCreating` additions for `Report`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(p => p.Image).HasColumnType("image");
modelBuilder.Entity<Report>().Property(p => p.Template).HasColumnType("image");
```

note that i had to put `image` as `ColumnType` because of `Byte array truncation to a length of 4000.` error.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Report report, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            if (files.ElementAt(0) != null && files.ElementAt(0).ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    files.ElementAt(0).InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    report.Image = ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }

            if (files.ElementAt(1) != null && files.ElementAt(1).ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    files.ElementAt(1).InputStream.CopyTo(ms1);
                    report.Template = ms1.GetBuffer();
                }

            }
            db.Reports.Add(report);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Temporary save method
            var tempID = 10000000 + report.ReportID;
            var fileName = tempID.ToString(); //current by-pass for name
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Report/"), fileName);
            files.ElementAt(1).SaveAs(path);

            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Hopefully you may notice what I'm missing.

Comment: Ok, so obviously something is going on.  Can you check these things: 1. place a breakpoint on `report.Template = ms1.GetBuffer();` Is this line being executed? 2. what is the value of `report.Template` right before calling `SaveChanges()` (is it null, or does it have a value with a greater than 0 length)?  Does the report get written to the database at all with just the Template empty, or does nothing get written at all?

Comment: Also, try removing the `RequiredAttribute` from the property all together and see what happens.

Comment: If I remove `[Required]` from model it works, and no it does not save anything so I'm guessing there's something wrong with value. I'll debug and let you know. Sorry for late response I was away yesterday.

Comment: I've debugged it and it doesn't even reach the `Create/POST` method. It sees `Template` as empty. Regardless of `RequiredCollectionAttribute` or `RequiredAttribute`. Happens the same.

Comment: You said if you remove the `RequiredAttribute` it worked?  What does `Template` get set to in that case? On the line above where you are setting the value to `Template`, what does 'files.ElementAt(1)' return?

Comment: Also, try using `ms1.ToArray()` instead of `.GetBuffer()`.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that too. But I seem to have found a workaround, and was wondering what you'd think of it. I'll update question with it.

Comment: The `files.ElementAt(1)` returns nothing, and `Template` get set to nothing also. If there is `RequiredAttribute`. If there isn't it gets set to files binary value as it should. No difference so far with `ms1.ToArray();` instead of `ms1.GetBuffer();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've altered my `Create` method, and this is what I've come up with. Seems to work fine, but...

```
if (files.ElementAt(1) != null && files.ElementAt(1).ContentLength > 0)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        files.ElementAt(1).InputStream.CopyTo(ms1);
        report.Template = ms1.GetBuffer();
    }

}
else // this part of code did the trick, although not sure how good it is in practice
{
    return View(report);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `RequiredAttribute` checks for null and an empty string.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
  if (value == null)
    return false;
  string str = value as string;
  if (str != null && !this.AllowEmptyStrings)
    return str.Trim().Length != 0;
  else
    return true;
}
```

This works fine if your byte array is null, but you probably want to check for an empty array as well (without seeing how you are assigning the value of your `Template` property, I can only guess that this is the case).  You can define your own required attribute that does this check for you.

```
public class RequiredCollectionAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
      bool isValid = base.IsValid(value);

      if(isValid)
      {
        ICollection collection = value as ICollection;
        if(collection != null)
        {
            isValid = collection.Count != 0;
        }
      }  
      return isValid;
    }
}
```

Now just replace the `Required` attribute on your `Template` property with our new `RequiredCollection` attribute.

```
[RequiredCollection]
public byte[] Template {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for swift response, I will try this out now :)

Comment: Same thing happens :( It refuses to save it to database... :( I will update my question with Controller.

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked around the posts and notice people use custom validation
>   but they have used HttpPostedFileBase as types of files instead of
>   byte[] like me..

Do you want to bind the posted file to a byterray field in the model? If yes you have to go for a custom model binder.

ASP.NET MVC already has a built-in model binder for byte array so you can easily extend that as suggested in this [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/model_binding_posted_file_to_byte_array).

```
public class CustomFileModelBinder : ByteArrayModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var file = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Files[bindingContext.ModelName];
 
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength != 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                var fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                return fileBytes;
            }
 
            return null;
        }
 
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Remove(typeof(byte[]));
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(byte[]), new CustomFileModelBinder());
}
```

Now the uploaded file will directly come and sit as bytearray in the properties.

Comment: I've tried this solution too, but same thing is happening. I'm guessing it's bit trickier then I thought.